# Why can't I use Spring:url in an href?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I have seen several examples using

```
 <a href="<spring:url value='/about/' />" >About </a>
```

I try this and get an error from Jetty

```
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/footer.jspx(6,22) The value of attribute "href" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
```

Is there some encoding setting I have overlooked?

This is unfortunate because the other examples of using spring url I have seen are ugly

```
<spring:url value='/about' var="about_url" />
<a href="${about_url}" title="About MyFit">About MyFit</a>
```

Do I really need an additional line for every hyperlink in my templates?

Is this something that is fairly trivial and I have overlooked?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this? Having a spring:url tag for every url link is too verbose! Perhaps make it into an inline function like ${fn:trim('some string')}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `.jspx` file, which must be a well-formed XML document. In `.jsp` files it would work fine.

Comment: ouch. I am using Roo which auto generates the .jspx haven't looked in to if it will support .jsp yet. Is there any way to be less verbose in .jspx? What are the benefits of .jspx over .jsp?

Comment: Would be nice if it was a separate question. :)